# What is the Thingsboard IoT platform's default system administrator account?

Tags: thingsboard

What is the Thingsboard IoT platform's (https://thingsboard.io) default system administrator account after a fresh (Raspberry Pi) installation?

The existing documentation only refers to default "tenant" account, which is ok on my setup.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

Default system administrator account:

- login - sysadmin@thingsboard.org
- password - sysadmin

Default demo tenant administrator account:

- login - tenant@thingsboard.org.
- password - tenant.

Demo tenant customers:

Customer A user: customerA@thingsboard.org.

Customer B user: customerB@thingsboard.org.

Customer C user: customerC@thingsboard.org.

all users have “customer” password.

Take a look at [demo-account](https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/demo-account/) documentation page for more information.